# Power Bi: Refresh "Publish to Web" link

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created Power Bi dashboards using Sql Azure as Data Source. I have published the reports on to the Power BI Portal and enabled a scheduled refresh policy. The reports are getting refreshed without any issue in the portal.

I have used the "Publish to Web" option and used the link to show the dashboards to other users. But this link doesn't get refreshed even when the report is refreshed in the Power Bi Portal.

Can I get some help in this regard.

Thanks!!

Comment: Same issue is happening with many of the public reports and irrespective of the browser... Probably report is getting refreshed in some time mostly.! Not sure how much time it takes, can some official could answer this better.!

Comment: For worst case, I will delete the existing report and publish as new report from desktop.. Later Publish to web to get web link, which will get it replaced in portal... Try if does it helps

Comment: I have the same issue but can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use? Have you tried the incognito window? Maybe it's a cookies issue.

Comment: This is not answering question, can be mention in comment.!

Comment: It is not a browser caching issue I cleared everything and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

in Power BI web click on setting gear and go to Manage Embedded Codes, here you will see a list of currently published public links, you need to remove the currently published link for your report before recreating a new one to have your changes reflected in the public published one.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErJnO.png)